# Setting Scale Dependent Visibility for WMS in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, pyqgis, scale

This code imports 'MiniScale' mapping from my WMS

```
miniScale = 'crs=EPSG:27700&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/jpeg&layers=9&styles=&url=http://192.000.0.00:0000/wms_service'
miniScaleLayer = QgsRasterLayer(miniScale, 'MiniScale', 'wms')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(miniScaleLayer)
```

Using similar code, I can add WMS feeds for all the other mapping types.

Of course, WMS feeds should appear and disappear as the user zooms in and out, and this is achieved via the scale dependent visibility.

How can I specify the scale dependent visibility for these layers? I can manually set this up via the layer's properties dialog, but it'd be great if these layers could be added in with the properties pre-set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this (in QGIS v.2.8.1):

```
miniScale = 'crs=EPSG:27700&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/jpeg&layers=9&styles=&url=http://192.000.0.00:0000/wms_service'
miniScaleLayer = QgsRasterLayer(miniScale, 'MiniScale', 'wms')        

# Set scale based visibility
miniScaleLayer.setScaleBasedVisibility(True)
miniScaleLayer.setMaximumScale(100000)
miniScaleLayer.setMinimumScale(500000)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(miniScaleLayer)
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm now returning `QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'setScaleBasedVisibility'`

Comment: If you happen to use QGIS < v.2.8, try with `miniScaleLayer.toggleScaleBasedVisibility(True)`, instead of `miniScaleLayer.setScaleBasedVisibility(True)`, the rest would remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, works also in PyQGIS3, just the values in the provided example needs to be swapped: 
`miniScaleLayer.setMaximumScale(100000)
miniScaleLayer.setMinimumScale(500000)`